# My android app shows a video and must be always running, but after few hours my app is stopped

Tags: android

I'm new on android application and i'm creating an app that shows a video using a VideoView, I use a CountDownTimer to search each 15 seconds for video updates and play another video. My app works very well during 2 or 3 hours but after this my app just stop, the application doesn't close but is stopped and I must close and open again. What should I do? Thanks.

Comment: "What should I do?" - Well, you can start by showing some relevant code.

Comment: post your crash log. thanks

Comment: what does "stop" mean?  Apps don't stop, they either pause or terminate.  If they terminate with a failure, something will be logged.

Answer (score 0):

It literally stops on the screen, it stops the timer and video view.
Here is the code that i'm using to count time to call functions to show video and time.

```
new CountDownTimer(20000, 1000) {
             public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                time++;
                downloadTime++;
                if(downloadTime == 2){  // Should be executed each 2 seconds
                    DoDownloads();
                    downloadTime = 0; //
                }
                    showPlayer();
                    showTime();

             }

             public void onFinish() {
                 this.start();
             }
          }.start();
```

I can't show any log because this happens after some hours and can be 2 hours or 10 hours, and i'm testing on tablet.

Answer (score 0):

We would need the code of the rest of your functions, like `DoDownloads();  showPlayer(); showTime();`

anyways, i wouldnt restart the countdown that way. Id try with a handler and  postdelayed(Runnable), like:

```
private Handler handler = new Handler();

private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
            time++;
            downloadTime++;
            if(downloadTime == 2){  // Should be executed each 2 seconds
                DoDownloads();
                downloadTime = 0; //
            }
                showPlayer();
                showTime();

     handler.postDelayed(this, tiempo);
   }
};

handler.postDelayed(runnable, tiempo);
```

And also, you should debug the app and copy/past the log cast in the moment it fails, and give us some information about in what point the execution wsa